# Elements contain in a sigma algebra generated by a set of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

Hello and thanks for the time spend to read this :)

Consider $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$

Consider $A=\{x_1,...,x_p\}$ a set of random variables and $\Theta=\sigma(A)$ be the sigma algebra generated by $\{x_1,...,x_p\}$.

Moreover consider $A'$ and $A''$ such that $A'\dot\cup A''=A$ (where $\dot\cup$ represent the disjoint union) and $\mathcal{A}=\sigma(A')$ and $\mathcal{B}=\sigma (A'')$ the sigma algebras generated by $A'$ and $A''$. Finally consider $\mathcal{G}=\{A\cap B:A\in\mathcal{A}\;\text{and}\;B\in\mathcal{B}\}$.

I am asking myself if the following question :
is it true that for all $\theta \in \Theta$ we have $\theta\in \mathcal{A}$, or $\theta\in \mathcal{B}$ or $\theta \in \mathcal{G}$ ?

It seems intuitively true, but I am not 100% sure and unable to prove it.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Mathieu

Comment: No, in general $\sigma(A)$ is much larger than $\mathcal A\cup\mathcal B\cup\mathcal G$, consider for example $A'=\{X\}$, $A''=\{Y\}$, say, with $X$ and $Y$ i.i.d. uniform on $[0,1]$, and the event $\{X<Y\}$. But of course $\sigma(A)\subseteq\mathcal F$... as every sigma-algebra involving only objects measurable with respect to $\mathcal F$.

Comment: By definition random variables are measurable maps, so $\Theta\subseteq\mathcal{F}$. I guess you meant "is it true that for all $\theta\in\Theta$ we have $\theta\in\mathcal{A}$, or $\theta\in\mathcal{B}$ or $\theta\in\mathcal{G}$". In this case this is not true: Note that $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}\subseteq\mathcal{G}$, but $\mathcal{G}$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra in general (it is not closed under unions).

Comment: Thanks both of you for your answers. And yeah I meant $\mathcal{G}$ and not $\mathcal{F}$.